# resize algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I'm using the algorithmic package and was wondering if there is a way to resize/rescale the algorithm.
Currently, for some reason, the algorithm exceeds the right margin of a letter size paper and I want to shift it to satisfy the specified letter right margin.

This is the code I'm using (the only difference is that I'm using it in a double-column version)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage[left=0.58in, right=0.58in, top=0.71in]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}[t] 
{       
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE {\bf Input}: $N, \rho, T$.
\FOR {$t=0,1,2,\cdots,T-1$}
\STATE Do the following actions in order to get the output of the algorithm
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{my algorithm \label{algo}}
}   
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I think now I understand the issue. For some reason, IEEE template does not encourage using the algorithm.sty package. If I only use the algorithmic package, then I would lose the possibility to add a caption. Is there a way to include a caption with only algorithmic.sty or algorithmic.sty, without resorting to algorithm.sty or algorithm2e.sty.

Comment: you can use a smaller font, `\small` for example

Comment: Most (all?) algorithm packages use a list-like environment for setting the statements. So, there should be automatic line-wrapping enabled. If you have lines extending into the right margin it may be because of some other issue. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this problematic behaviour? Something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried that but it seems to resize the text not the border of the algorithms, which I can think is what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Werner: I just did that. Thanks.

Comment: Your minimal example does not replicate your problem... even with the `twocolumn` option.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I edited the minimal example.

Comment: It is impossible to understand your question, an algorithm is _text_ and you said it was too wide to fit, `\small` would make the text smaller and would be the answer to the question, but your example code does not have an over-wide algorithm line. I can not guess what you mean by resizing the border: what border do you mean?

Comment: unrelated but `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993. `\textbf{Input}` would be  the LaTeX markup.

Comment: @Chao: I can't replicate your problem with the code you've given. The algorithm works without problem, and everything fits within the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}` and `\end{minipage}` before and after your algorithm. Here is an example

```
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth} 


\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
initialization\;
\While{While condition}{
    instructions\;
    \eIf{condition}{
        instructions1\;
        instructions2\;
    }{
        instructions3\;
    }
}
\caption{An algorithms}
\end{algorithm}



\end{minipage}
```